# fix last li and scroll at ul firefox issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

Its working perfect in Crome but in firefox **second-last list item** **'country name 8'** is not visible, you can see it through firebug.

**conditions:-**

1. Cant use div or another tag for last list item it has to be in li.
2. It has to display inside the scroll not outside.

only two conditions. 
if its possible through jquery we can do that,
*Thanks in advance :)*

```css
.searchlist{
 position: relative;
  margin-top:50px;
}
ul{  display: block;
    max-height: 110px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    padding:0px 0px 38px 0px;
 margin:0px;
 width: 223px;
 }
li{padding: 8px 10px;
display: block;
font-size: 13px;
cursor: pointer;
background: #35404d;
}
li.fix{border-top: 1px solid #50575f;
    position: absolute;
    top: 115px;
    width: 185px;}
```

```html
<div class="searchlist">
 <ul>
  <li>country name 1 </li>
  <li>country name 2 </li>
  <li>country name 3 </li>
  <li>country name 4 </li>
  <li>country name 5 </li>
  <li>country name 6 </li>
  <li>country name 7 </li>
  <li>country name 8 </li>
  <li class="fix">country name 9 </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You an remove the padding for `ul` and target the second last li and add the bottom margin to it.

You can use [`:nth-last-child(2)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child). [Browser compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child#Browser_compatibility)

```
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
```

**Demo**

```css
.searchlist {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
ul {
  display: block;
  max-height: 110px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0px;
  width: 223px;
}
li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #35404d;
}
li:nth-last-child(2) {
  margin-bottom: 34px;
}
li.fix {
  border-top: 1px solid #50575f;
  position: absolute;
  top: 69%;
  width: 185px;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchlist">
  <ul>
    <li>country name 1</li>
    <li>country name 2</li>
    <li>country name 3</li>
    <li>country name 4</li>
    <li>country name 5</li>
    <li>country name 6</li>
    <li>country name 7</li>
    <li>country name 8</li>
    <li class="fix">country name 9</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Actually i tried this to, but I have one more scenario where my last list item is not fixed in that case this will create a Problem. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: You can give a class to the ul according to the scenarios for eg. `.regular or .fixed` and in CSS you can have `ul.fixed li:nth-last-child(2) ` so that it fixes for only one scenario

Answer (score 0):

One of the best **solution** is this, because those who perhaps want to make an element remain fixed while it is **scrolling** up and down!

```css
body {
  margin: 10px;
}

ul {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

li {
  padding: 8px 10px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

li.fixed {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  color: #f2f2f2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item1</li>
  <li>Item2</li>
  <li>Item3</li>
  <li>Item4</li>
  <li>Item5</li>
  <li>Item6</li>
  <li>Item7</li>
  <li>Item8</li>
  <li>Item9</li>
  <li>Item10</li>
  <li>Item11</li>
  <li>Item12</li>
  <li>Item13</li>
  <li>Item14</li>
  <li>Item15</li>
  <li>Item16</li>
  <li>Item17</li>
  <li>Item18</li>
  <li>Item19</li>
  <li>Item20</li>
  <li>Item21</li>
  <li>Item22</li>
  <li>Item23</li>
  <li>Item24</li>
  <li>Item25</li>
  <li>Item26</li>
  <li>Item27</li>
  <li>Item28</li>
  <li>Item29</li>
  <li>Item30</li>
  <li>Item31</li>
  <li>Item32</li>
  <li>Item33</li>
  <li>Item34</li>
  <li>Item35</li>
  <li>Item36</li>
  <li>Item37</li>
  <li>Item38</li>
  <li>Item39</li>
  <li>Item40</li>
  <li>Item41</li>
  <li>Item42</li>
  <li>Item43</li>
  <li>Item44</li>
  <li>Item45</li>
  <li>Item46</li>
  <li>Item47</li>
  <li>Item48</li>
  <li>Item49</li>
  <li>Item50</li>
  <li class="fixed">HEADER</li>
</ul>
```